# Not able to Delete a Partition

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I am trying to extend my C drive as it has very little space remaining.
I tried to delete G drive to create free space for C drive but Disk Management is not allowing me to delete G drive. I do not understand what the problem is but I think it is something to do with System written on G drive.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: There is no image in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to delete G in order to extend C.

You can use a third-party partition editor to move G to the end of the
unallocated space, so that the unallocated space now follows C.

You will then be able to extend C over as much of this unallocated space
as you want, where the maximum size will be 98+566=664 GB.

An example third-party product is
[AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition Freeware](https://www.diskpart.com/free-partition-manager.html).
You will need to boot from its
[Bootable CD](https://www.diskpart.com/help/make-bootable-cd-wizard.html)
in order to
[Resize/Move Partition](https://www.diskpart.com/help/resize-partition.html).

Take full backups before doing any partition work.

Answer (score 0):

"System" (as well as "Active") means it's the partition which holds the OS bootloader – the program which starts Windows in the beginning.

(Normally that would be the job of either that small 500M partition when it's present, or the C: partition otherwise. But it's possible that this is a leftover from some previous installation.)

Run `bcdboot C:\Windows /s C:` to install the bootloader to the C: partition, then use Disk Manager to mark the partition as "Active" and reboot.